# ¿Por qué obtengo este resultado en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Recientemente he visto una pregunta y no entiendo por qué el resultado me da un valor numérico si se trata de operaciones con cadenas de texto.

La operación es `"1" - - "1"`, y la lógica me indicaría que el resultado es `"11"`, pero es `2`.

```js
console.log("1" - - "1");
```

¿A qué se debe este comportamiento?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para concatenar Strings en JS se usa +, por lo que `"1" + "1"` retornará `"11"`

No se pueden realizar sustracciones(restas) en strings, así que JS convierte ambos "1" a números y realiza la operación, resultando `1--1 = 1+1 = 2`

Answer (score 4):

Creo que esto se llama coerción de tipos y es un fenómeno de javascript, que trata de convertir el valor a un formato adecuado para la operación a realizar.

Lo que ocurre es que en la siguiente expresión:

```
console.log("1" - - "1");
```

El primer `-` representa la operación restar y javascript entiende que debería convertir el primer 1 a entero para realizar esta operación entonces tenemos esto:

```
console.log(1 - - "1");
```

Luego se encuentra otro signo de restar y una cadena, entonces javascript tratara de cambiar el formato a uno adecuado es decir a entero convirtiendo el `-"1"` a `-1` entonces tenemos esto:

```
console.log(1 - (- 1));
```

Se agrega el paréntesis por regla matemática además de que dos signos de resta es decir negativos dan resultado una suma, quedando así:

```
console.log(1 + 1);
```

Entonces esto son los cambios:

```
>> "1" - - "1"
>> 1 - - "1"
>> 1 - (-1)
>> 1 + 1
= 2
```

Answer (score 3):

El primer guión es un operador aritmético, como el segundo guión está separado del primero, lo considera como el negativo del segundo valor e indirectamente toma el segundo "1" como un número entero negativo (-1) y hace este cálculo:

```
1 - (-1) = 2
```

Comment: Me gustó que aclaraste que el segundo guión está separado y eso lo considera como negativo del segundo número, ya que al estar juntos marcaría error